# API search in mediawiki don't work

Tags: mediawiki

I want to make search with wikimedia API in my local mediawiki.

When I try this url on the wikipedia API online

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=fran&srprop=timestamp

I get this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
  <query-continue>
    <search sroffset="10" />
  </query-continue>
  <query>
    <searchinfo totalhits="13454" />
    <search>
      <p ns="0" title="Fran" timestamp="2013-07-10T11:08:52Z" />
      <p ns="0" title="Hurricane Fran" timestamp="2013-10-27T17:30:58Z" />
      <p ns="0" title="Fran Drescher" timestamp="2013-12-10T01:10:38Z" />
      <p ns="0" title="Fran Walsh" timestamp="2013-11-19T04:12:29Z" />
      <p ns="0" title="List of The Nanny characters" timestamp="2013-11-29T17:26:10Z" />
      <p ns="0" title="Fran González" timestamp="2013-07-16T14:44:50Z" />
      <p ns="0" title="Fran Landesman" timestamp="2013-08-02T19:36:03Z" />
      <p ns="0" title="Fran Mérida" timestamp="2013-12-08T23:27:28Z" />
      <p ns="0" title="Tropical Storm Fran" timestamp="2012-11-11T18:44:02Z" />
      <p ns="0" title="Fran (film)" timestamp="2013-10-30T11:49:53Z" />
    </search>
  </query>
</api>
```

When I type the same url in my mediawiki API with dump of wikipedia:

http://www.mylocalhost.com/begoo/assets/mediawiki/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=fran&srprop=timestamp

I get this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
  <query>
    <search />
  </query>
</api>
```

I correctly installed all dump of wikipedia and only the API OpenSearch Work fine,not the API Search.What is wrong?

Comment: Do all the other APIs work correctly?

Comment: yes all the other API work correctly but not API search

Comment: Default search namespaces, search integration, maybe a bug that is resolved now?